# Different approch to find the derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

[image]Let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be defined as follows

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
       \exp(-\frac{1}{1-x^2})\ \text{if}\ |x|<1\\ 0    \text{ 
       otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Show that this function is infinitely many times differentiable.
In the book the proof is given by induction. First they have shown that for $|x|<1$ , $f^n(x)= p_n(x) (1-x^2)^{(-2n) }\exp(-\frac{1}{1-x^2})$. Where $p_n$ is a polynomial in $x$.

And for $|x|>1$ $f^n(x)=0$. Then they have written that if $f^k(x)=0$ then $f^{(k+1)}(x)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 1}f^k(1+\theta_{k}(1-x))=0$. Where $\theta_k\in(0,1)$

I have added the picture containing this sentence

Now how they have written the last line?

Comment: I suppose $p_n$ is some kind of a polynomial depending on $n$. What is $\theta_k$?

Comment: I have added the terms

Comment: Comments (i) Your book surely also is proving by induction that $f^{(n)}(\pm1)=0$ (ii) Are you sure that in the last sentence some of the $x$s shouldn't be $1$s? [After all when $x>0$ the only $x$ with $f^k(x)=0$ are those with $x\ge 1$ and then it's trivial to see that $f^{(k+1)}(x)=0$ for $x>1$ so what is in question is whether $f^{(k+1)}(1)=0$.]